# Convert text to binary columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text

I have a column in my dataframe that contains many different companies separated by commas (assume there are additional rows with even more companies).

```
company
apple,microsoft,disney,nike
microsoft,adidas,amazon,eBay
```

I want to convert this to binary columns for every possible company that appears. It should ultimately look like this:

```
adidas  apple  amazon  eBay  disney  microsoft  nike  ...  last_store
0       1      0       0     1       1          1     ...  0
1       0      1       1     0       1          0     ...  0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let us try `get_dummies`

```
s=df.brand.str.get_dummies(',')
   adidas  amazon  apple  disney  eBay  microsoft  nike
0       0       0      1       1     0          1     1
1       1       1      0       0     1          1     0
```